# jquery function to select a button

Tags: jquery

How to select the clicked button element in  function below with jquery?

## HTML

```
<button class="btn" onclick="increase(2)">Click</button>
```

## Javascript

```
function increase(id){

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by select the clicked button element in function?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `this`

`<button class="btn" onclick="increase(this)">Click</button>`

```
function increase(thispass){
  console.log(thispass);
  $(thispass).css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

Or better yet you can bind the click event to the class and use `this`, avoiding the unnecessary inline OnClick handler. If you need to pass the increase value you can use a data-attribute in the button element.

`<button class="btn">Click</button>`

```
$(".btn").on('click', function(event){
  const inc = parseInt($(this).data('increase'), 10);
  console.log(inc);
});
```

Comment: I'd just mention to use `data-*` attribute instead of the discouraged inline `on*` handlers.

Comment: I like the data-attribute option, will update. Is the inline onClick handler discouraged?

Comment: Well, yes, it's always best to keep your JS code in one place, and not wonder where it's called, in which HTML file... also it's hard to debug.

Comment: So yeah, I'd use `data-increase="2"` and read that value using `const inc = parseInt($(this).data('increase'), 10);`

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple elements with same `class`, if you want to go with pure javascript way, try pass element also with value, like this `<button class="btn" onclick="increase(this, 1)` on click.

```js
function increase(element, value) {
  element.classList.add('Clicked')
  console.log(value)
}
```

```css
.Clicked {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="increase(this, 1)">Click</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="increase(this, 2)">Click</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="increase(this, 3)">Click</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="increase(this, 4)">Click</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="increase(this, 5)">Click</button>
```

`this` return element that you clicked, and you can do what you want, such add class or etc, also second arg return `value`

**Update:** And here is `jQuery` way:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('Clicked')
  let value = $(this).data('value');
  console.log(value)
});
```

```css
.Clicked {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" data-value="1">Click</button>
<button class="btn" data-value="2">Click</button>
<button class="btn" data-value="3">Click</button>
<button class="btn" data-value="4">Click</button>
<button class="btn" data-value="5">Click</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function increase(ele, id) {
  console.log("The clicked element's class name is: " + ele.getAttribute("class"));
  console.log("The clicked element's innerHTML is: " + ele.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="increase(this,2)">Click</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

your first part of question is how to select. You can select clicked button from id so to do this you will assign the id for your button. no need to inline onclick function, well its totally up to you.

```
<button id= "btn1" class="btn">Click</button>
```

and here you can do whatever you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        alert("button"); // do increase here
    }); 
});
```